# laravel-5.7: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm new to Laravel and trying to add `Product` under `Category` but when I add `Product` then it shows this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` ..."

Initially i was adding these products without under any category than it was working and now its not adding under `Category`.

can anyone would prefer to provide me its solution?

here is my form:

```html
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('admin/add-product') }}" name="add_product" id="add_product" novalidate="novalidate">{{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Under Category</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <select name="category_id" id="category_id" style="width:220px;">
                <?php echo $categories_drop_down; ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name">
            </div>
          </div>
  <div class="uploader" id="uniform-undefined"><input name="image" id="image" type="file" size="19" style="opacity: 0;"><span class="filename">No file selected</span><span class="action">Choose File</span></div>
  div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Product" class="btn btn-success">
          </div>
        </form>
```

here is `ProductsController`:

**ProductsController.php**

```php
public function addProduct(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $product = new Product;
        $product->product_name = $data['product_name'];
        $product->product_code = $data['product_code'];
        $product->product_color = $data['product_color'];
        if ( ! empty($data['description']))
        {
            $product->description = $data['description'];
        }
        else
        {
            $product->description = '';
        }
        $product->price = $data['price'];

        // Upload Image
        if ($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $image_tmp = Input::file('image');
            if ($image_tmp->isValid())
            {
                $extension = $image_tmp->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename = rand(111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
                $large_image_path = 'images/backend_images/products/large/' . $filename;
                $medium_image_path = 'images/backend_images/products/medium/' . $filename;
                $small_image_path = 'images/backend_images/products/small/' . $filename;
                // Resize Images
                Image::make($image_tmp)->save($large_image_path);
                Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(600, 600)->save($medium_image_path);
                Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(300, 300)->save($small_image_path);
                // Store image name in products table
                $product->image = $filename;
            }
        }

        $product->save();

        /*return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success','Product has been added successfully!');*/

        return redirect('/admin/view-products')->with('flash_message_success', 'Product has been added successfully!');
    }

    $categories = Category::where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();
    $categories_drop_down = "<option value='' selected disabled>Select</option>";

    foreach ($categories as $cat)
    {
        $categories_drop_down .= "<option value='" . $cat->id . "'>" . $cat->name . "</option>";
        $sub_categories = Category::where(['parent_id' => $cat->id])->get();
        foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_cat)
        {
            $categories_drop_down .= "<option value='" . $sub_cat->id . "'>&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;" . $sub_cat->name . "</option>";
        }
    }

    return view('admin.products.add_product')->with(compact('categories_drop_down'));
}
```

Comment: When you initialise a new product you're not setting the category_id. `if ($request->isMethod('post'))` within this block set category_id. The error informs you where the issue is. It's not an issue with Laravel, rather DB configuration, which is actually the behaviour you want.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you show us your Post and Category model classes.

Answer (score 2):

Although, there would be better ways to write this problem, the immediate solution would be to set the category_id field of your Product.

```
$product->product_name = $data['product_name'];
$product->product_code = $data['product_code'];
$product->product_color = $data['product_color'];

// Add this:
$product->category_id = $data['category_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you have here is that in your migration you have category_id is not nullable which means it should have a value assigned to it from the controller you can either assign a value for it from your controller or you can go to your migration file and add this line

```
$table->integer('catagory_id')->nullable();
```

Then you will remigrate the table and it shouldn't throw this error again, but I prefer that you assign a value for it if you have relationship or something you want to connect it to it but if you don't have relationships then the entire `category_id` is useless in my point of view

If you want to assign a value to it, you should do something like this in your controller after the new product line:

```
$product->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
```

because your controller didn't take the value of the input which has the name of

```
category_id
```

Comment: bro m making the relationship of product with categories and cant make it nullable, and m also assigning a value to it but i dint know why it is not working

Comment: is there any mistake in controller because it is edited?

Comment: I am not seeing you assigninig a value to it bro you assignedname code color description price and the file name with its extention

Comment: any suggestion would u prefer to done this task? or how can i assign a value to it

Comment: you should do something like this 
in your controller after the new product line
$product->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
bcs your controller didn't take the value of the input which has the name of
 category_id

Comment: so happy for you ❤️

Answer (score -2):

As the error implies, it does not have a default value, you could solve it by either create a migration (or revise the one you had) so the column 'category_id' is nullable or just add the following line in the product creation:

```
$product->category_id = NULL;
```

You may find more information if needed about nullable at [Laravel migration documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#creating-columns)

Comment: now it saying Creating default object from empty value and hilighting the above code

Comment: Place it after $product = new Product; does it work for you?

Comment: Which one this time?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value